# Unable to extract data in a single .csv file from Google Big Query (though data is smaller than 1GB)

Tags: google-bigquery, export-to-csv

I am able to export the data in 4 different files of about 90 MB each. (which doesn't make sense)

I have read the limitations of Google Big Query and it says that data with more than 1 GB in size cannot be downloaded in a single CSV file.

My data size is about 250 - 300 MB in size.

This is what usually I do to export data from GBQ:

I saved the table in Google Big Query (as it has more than 16000 rows)

Then exported it in the Bucket using as follows:

```
 gs://[your_bucket]/file-name-*.csv
```

I think 2M rows of data is less than 1 GB. (Let me know if I am wrong)

Can I get this data in a single csv file ?

Thank you.

Comment: 2M rows can be bigger than 1GB, depending on what's in the rows (number of columns, data type)

Comment: the data is around 350 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take out the wildcard from the name of the blob you want to write to. [This tells BQ you want to export as multiple files.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files)

So you should rather export to  `gs://[your_bucket]/file-name.csv`

As you noted, this won't work if your data is bigger than 1GB, but you should be fine if total is about 300MB.

Answer (score 0):

You can get node.js readable stream that contains result of your query (https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/2.0.x/BigQuery#createQueryStream).
Chunk of data is a row of result set.
And then write data (row by row) to csv (locally or to cloud storage).